# Combining multiple subject ID's

Tags: sas, rows

I have a table with a few thousand records sorted by distinct subject id, however in some cases the  subject name appears multiple times if the subject used more than one id type, so one time the subject is using their social and another time their passport, and maybe a third time their drivers liscense.

The data is structured like this.

```
name            id_type                  id_num
suzy smith      passport                 123
suzy smith      ssn                      123456789
suzy smith      drivers liscense         A3456789
```

I would like it to look like this.

```
name        id_type      id_num
suzy smith  ssn          123456789
suzy smith  ssn          123456789
suzy smith  ssn          123456789
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Which id_type wins? What logic do you want to use to select the row when you have more than one? Could you please elaborate and add some details to your question?

Comment: Since ssn seems to be the id_type you chose.. Does your data contain ssn for every subject? Do you want to keep duplicate rows in your final result with identical info?

Comment: It doesnt matter which type of id wins. I need to keep all the rows, but since i'm counting subject by their id, i need the subject to have one id number.So if Suzy made three transactions using a different id each time, ssn, then passport, then drivers liscense, I'm counting her transactions by her id, because names are not unique in a big data set. So Suzy needs to have one consistent id assigned, doesn't matter which id type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sort the original data set ("have") by name:

```
proc sort data=have;
    by name;
run;
```

Then set test by name and rename id_type to old_id_type. Do the same for id_num. Retain id_type and id_num. Then set id_type equal to old_id_type if a given record is the first instance of a person's name. Do the same for id_num.

```
data final;
    set test (rename=(id_type=old_id_type id_num = old_id_num));
    by name;
    retain id_type id_num;
    if first.name then do;
        id_type = old_id_type;
        id_num = old_id_num;
    end;
    drop old_id_type old_id_num;
run;
```

When you retain a variable, the value is kept from one observation to the next unless you reset the value. Thus each person will have the first id_type and id_num for all instances of that name.

Answer (score 0):

I used the retain statement and added more code. Here is the full code:

```
DATA TEST;
SET C;
BY SUBJ_NAME;
RETAIN N(0);
IF FIRST.SUBJ_NAME THEN N=1;
ELSE N=N+1;
RUN;

PROC SORT
DATA=WORK.TEST
OUT=TTSORTED;
BY SUBJ_NAME N;
RUN;

PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=TTSORTED    
OUT=TTTEST
PREFIX=Column
NAME=Source
LABEL=Label;
BY SUBJ_NAME N ;
VAR SUBJ_INDENT;
RUN; QUIT;
DATA TEST2;
SET TTTEST;
NEW_ID=CATS(SOURCE,N);
RUN; 

PROC SORT
DATA=WORK.TEST2(KEEP=Column1 NEW_ID SUBJ_NAME SBJT_ID)
OUT=WORK.TMP0_INPUT;
BY SUBJ_NAME SBJT_ID;
RUN;

PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=TMP0_INPUT 
OUT=SPLIT_TEST2;
BY SUBJ_NAME;
WHERE SUBJ_NAME NE ' ';
ID NEW_ID ;
VAR Column1;
RUN; QUIT;

DATA X;
SET  SPLIT_TEST2(RENAME = (SUBJ_NAME=SUBJ_NAME_NEW));
IF SUBJ_INDENT2 NE ' ' THEN SUBJ_INDENT3= SUBJ_INDENT2;
IF SUBJ_INDENT2 = ' ' THEN  SUBJ_INDENT3= SUBJ_INDENT1;
```

KEEP SUBJ_NAME_NEW SUBJ_INDENT1 SUBJ_INDENT2 SUBJ_INDENT3 ;
RUN;